# Is Cassandra faster than HBase on a single node cluster?

Tags: cassandra, hbase

I am planning to design a system that needs to scale to large amounts of data. At the beginning of its operation it will work with a small dataset with a limited budget, so it must also work well on a small dataset.

As far as I know HBase does not work well on small datasets and it needs at least a 5 node cluster. But this configuration is expensive for the moment. I know that both HBase and Cassandra are good solutions for large dataset. But is Cassandra faster on a single node with a small dataset?

I assume that Cassandra doesn't have problems on small datasets since all nodes are identical being based on a P2P system. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

Cassandra and hbase have different performance characteristics, and while there are some problems that both of them are good at, you should probably chose the database that is best for your application, not how the database performs for small data sets.

Not knowing much about your problem, I would probably just start with a simple sql database, and worry about scaling when you need to.

You can run cassandra on a single node, and it will work fine.

I suspect you can run hbase using multiple vm's on a single physical machine.

Comment: If I start with a SQL database I would latter need to migrate which may not be trivial. I can run HBase on multiple VMs, but with a poor performance.

Comment: If you chose the wrong nosql database, you may still need to migrate.  Do the simplest thing that works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a single node Hbase too. 
Anyway remember that single node Hbase/Cassandra is not comparable in performance to several nodes, since you don't have replication.